# Kivy Garden chart drawing over itself in

Tags: python, kivy

I have a pretty simple Kivy Garden Chart drawn in my app. I want to update this chart in real-time by adding values to the data series. When I add extra data to the MeshLinePlot series that the chart is showing, the chart updates nicely but unfortunately leaves the old chart shown on the screen. If I resize the window, the chart is redrawn with the correct data and none of the artifacts, but I can't find a way to force that in code. The code I'm using is this:

```
class ChartView(BoxLayout):
    dataPoints = NumericProperty(0)
    dataPlot = MeshLinePlot(color=[1, 0, 0, 1])
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ChartView, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        myChart = kvFind(self, 'rcid', 'testGraph')
        self.add_test_data()
        myChart.add_plot(self.dataPlot)

    def add_test_data(self):
        myChart = kvFind(self, 'rcid', 'testGraph')
        self.dataPoints += 1000
        self.dataPlot.points = [(x, random() - random() + sin(x / 100.)) for x in xrange(0, self.dataPoints)]
        myChart.xmax = self.dataPoints
```

What am I doing wrong? It's quite baffling.

Comment: Are you by any chance on a mac? There's a bug report for this already: https://github.com/kivy-garden/garden.graph/issues/8

Comment: That's very interesting - will see if I can repro that bug.